# Access 2010 SQL-- Order rows by aggregate function in crosstab query

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, ms-access-2010, aggregate-functions, crosstab

I want to see a **SUM** (Transform Spending) for each of my **rows** (Category) and pivoted by another **field** (Media_Type). The code below works fine for this, except for the ORDER BY clause, which I added because I want my output rows to be ordered by the ***total*** spending for each row.

```
TRANSFORM  Sum([Spending])

SELECT     [Category],
           SUM([Spending])
FROM       [Data]
GROUP BY   [Category]
ORDER BY   SUM([Spending]) DESC

PIVOT      [Media_Type] IN ("TV","Print","Internet")
;
```

When I add the ORDER BY command, I get the error: 'Cannot have aggregate function in ORDER BY clause'.  How can I work around this and group my rows by and aggregate?

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f761e950-10db-4a94-b1e6-89f3b9ed8e42/how-to-sort-by-an-aggregate-column-in-ms-access) suggests that your SQL should work, an alternative (but by no means great) option would be to move your query into the `FROM` part of another query e.g.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM (
    -- Your Query Here (but you'll have to name the SUM column) --
) x 
ORDER BY 
    columnName DESC`
```

I'm guessing Access doesn't have the [`OVER`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause available in SQL Server which could potentially be used otherwise.

Comment: The problem is the crosstab query. ORDER BY and aggregate function works if it is not inside the TRANSFORM statement. Also, the code you wrote would work except Access doesn't allow you to put a crosstab query into a subquery. It would work if I could call the other query, but for my purposes, it needs to all be in one query!

Answer (score 0):

```
TRANSFORM  Sum([Spending])
```

SELECT [Category], SUM([Spending]) as sum FROM [Data] GROUP BY [Category] ORDER BY sum DESC

PIVOT      [Media_Type] IN ("TV","Print","Internet")
;